# Redirect aliases to a specific folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

I need to redirect a specific domain aliases to a specific folder in main domain. Well, I'll  have only one host with the main domain data, I need do it:

```
http://a.com/
-> redirect automatically to: http://a.com/project-a
-> currently done

http://a.com/project-a
http://a.com/project-b
-> no redirect, it is the final folder
-> currently done

### HERE: ###
http://b.com/
-> redirect transparently to: http://a.com/project-b
-> I need do that!
```

Note that: the `b.com/...` need redirect all to `a.com/project-b/...` transparently. So, for instance:

```
http://b.com/ => http://a.com/project-b/
http://b.com/news => http://a.com/project-b/news
```

I need know how I can do it in .htaccess file. The domain aliases are ok, but currently both `a.com` and `b.com` redirect to `a.com` host (it's correct), but `b.com` need work in a specific folder.

I don't know if it is a problem, but the `/project-b` folder doesn't exists, it's a `mod_rewrite` to `index.php` only.

I don't want to redirect by 301, I need do all transparently (user will think that they are in `b.com` hosting).

Comment: 403 is not a redirect. no 4xx codes are. redirects are always 3xx.

Comment: Sorry! You are right! I mean 301 code! :D